# Going crazy with python set

Tags: python, set

Please take a look at the following snippet from ipython:

```
In [122]: len(netean)
Out[122]: 150

In [123]: len(nwrongpea)
Out[123]: 100

In [124]: len(set.intersection(set(nwrongpea), set(netean)))
Out[124]: 8

In [125]: len(set(nwrongpea) - set(netean))
Out[125]: 90

In [126]: len(set(netean) - set(nwrongpea))
Out[126]: 142
```

I am going crazy - since these two lists have the 8 elements in common (based on what intersection answers), how is it possible that [125] returns 90 ? Shouldn't that be 92 ?

Have I forgotten something from set theory  ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like one(or two) of this collections have some duplicate elements. So creating sets from them gives you sets with less number of elements..

Try `len(set(natean)) + len(set(nwrongpea))` and you'll see.

Comment: Actually there are 10 duplicates: (A u B) = (A - B) + (A !u B) + (B - A). In this case (A u B) = 90 + 8 + 142 = 240

Comment: Thanks 4 the answers! I dont have the data right now but probably the nwrongpea list has two duplicates. The data was not supposed to have duplicates thats why I didnt think of that. My mind is in peace now :-)was not supposed to have duplicates thats why I didnt think of that. My mind is in peace now :-)